# not able to install Text::Bidi CPAN module

Tags: perl, cpan

Trying to install [Text::Bidi](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aBidi) CPAN module, but failed. 
Getting this [error](http://www.dinkypage.com/errortextbidi). Do anybody know any work around for this?

```
OS : Ubuntu 10.04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the header files for `libfribidi`. I don't know Ubuntu's conventions, but if they're like Devian's you can find those in a package whose name ends with `-dev`.